# Typed Response in GET call

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement typed response in an easy GET but I get this strange behavior from compiler: the application is compiled but It returns a red error as you can see in the image taken from VS Code:

**ERROR in src/app/services/product.service.ts(49,5): error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.**

[image]

This is the code:

### src/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Device } from './model/device';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  devices: Device[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getAll();
  }

  getAll() {
    this.http.get<Device[]>('http://localhost:3000/devices')
      .subscribe(result => this.devices = result);
  }
}
```

### interface

```
export interface Device {
  id?: number;
  label?: string;
  os?: string;
  price?: number;
  memory?: number;
  rate?: number;
  desc?: string;
}
```

Why I get that error?

Thanks to support

Comment: Please share product.service.ts , whats the output of  `http://localhost:3000/devices`

Comment: Indeed, when an error message says there's a problem in a particular line of code, it is often useful to examine that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using a version of Angular that is pre v4.3
HttpClient became available in 4.3, which allows typed get. Before that you couldn't provide a type.